# Recreation of Default Web Site on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7

I've deleted by fault the `Default Web Site` into IIS 7. How do I please to add another one with `ASP.NET 4.0` configuration.

I've tried to add a new website `Default Web Site` with `ASP.NET 4.0` as pool and pointed it to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. But after creation, there is no `asp.net` folder under it. And when I've try to browse the web-app but I'm getting as error:

> The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path =
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\App_Data\NAMESPACE.MyDataContext.sdf
>   ]

Any brilliant idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have default setting like following.

[image]

Also set bindings like following.

[image]